# Avoid duplicate rows when join multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, left-join

I have problem with 3 tables: first (User) contains car dealers, second and third (Order_new, Car_demo) contains two types of cars sold by dealers. I need to sum number of sales and profit for a dealer.
Unfortunately it doesn't work correctly. One of dealer sold 11 cars from Order_new and 1 from Car_demo, but when I using COUNT a get 11 from Order_new (good) and 11 from Car_demo (not good...). The same with SUM - from Car_demo I get profit x 11.
This is important fragment of code:

```
SELECT
    d.name AS name,
    COUNT(cn_renault.id) AS ren_p,
    COUNT(cd_renault.id) AS ren_demo_p,
    SUM(cn_renault.profit) AS cn_profit,
    SUM(cd_renault.profit) AS cd_profit,
FROM User d
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        cd2.id AS id,
        cd2.dealer AS sale_by,
        cd2.price AS price,
    FROM Order_new cd2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Car car ON car.id = cd2.car_brand
    WHERE DATE(cd2.' . $by . ') >= \'' . $date . '\' AND DATE(cd2.' . $by . ') < \'' . $date_end . '\' AND car.brand = \'Renault\'
    GROUP BY cd2.id
) cn_renault ON cn_renault.sale_by = d.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        cd2.id AS id,
        cd2.sale_by AS sale_by,
        cd2.selling_price AS price,
    FROM Car_demo cd2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Car car ON car.id = cd2.car_brand
    WHERE DATE(cd2.' . $by_d . ') >= \'' . $date . '\' AND DATE(cd2.' . $by_d . ') < \'' . $date_end . '\' AND cd2.sale_status >= 2 AND car.brand = \'Renault\'
    GROUP BY cd2.id
) cd_renault ON cd_renault.sale_by = d.id
WHERE d.id = ' . $dealer_id . '
GROUP BY d.id
```

I know I can do it this way:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            COUNT(cd2.id) AS number_of,
            SUM(cd2.price) AS price,
        FROM Order_new cd2
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Car car ON car.id = cd2.car_brand
        WHERE DATE(cd2.' . $by . ') >= \'' . $date . '\' AND DATE(cd2.' . $by . ') < \'' . $date_end . '\' AND car.brand = \'Renault\'
        GROUP BY cd2.dealer
    ) cn_renault ON cn_renault.sale_by = d.id
```

and it works, but I need cars id to join another tables in query...

Any ideas?

Comment: Can u put it in sqlfiddle to get quicker answer

Comment: If you get a fragment to work, use it as a derived table as a defacto table on the inside of a join nest. That is a common strategy often